# Does Vuejs have similar API to remote asynchronous http calls (Ajax) as jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I know that Vuejs can be more effective than jQuery for DOM manipulation and user interactions handling. What about remote asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) calls? I'm searching for a Vue.js core API to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) as HTTP client for making api calls, I have created a `gateways` folder in my `src` folder and I have put files for each backend, creating [axios instances](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#creating-an-instance), like following

myApi.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1',
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    'X-Auth-Token': 'f2b6637ddf355a476918940289c0be016a4fe99e3b69c83d',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

You can look at detailed answer related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40830610/1610034) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40816212/1610034).

Comment: Just notice that vue-resource automatically makes 'this' the reference to the calling component/Vue instance. This is not the case with 'axios' (because it's a general purpose library) and so you must declare something like `var self=this;` before the call and reference `self` inside your promise (or use `bind`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as a separate file that you call from your page:
https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource